# How to constraint draggable object on a ring in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a draggable circle that can only move along a ring. Like
[image]

My thinking is first create a **Stack**. This **Stack** will have two children. First, a**Container** and make it a circle shape, and it has a **GestureDetetor** as its child. And second a another **Container** which is also circle shape and has a smaller radius （I thought this could cover up the region of **GestureDetector** which I do not want it to be active to any gestures).

My code is like,

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 200.0,
          height: 200.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              final handle = GestureDetector(
                onPanUpdate: _panHandler,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle,
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
              );
              return AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: valueListener,
                builder: (context, child) {
                  return Align(
                    alignment: Alignment(
                      (valueListener.value[0] * 2 - 1),
                      (valueListener.value[1] * 2 - 1),
                    ),
                    child: child,
                  );
                },
                child: handle,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 180.0,
          width: 180.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

However, this code cannot restrain the position circle at all...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constraining Draggable area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216747/constraining-draggable-area)

Comment: @OmerCelik Thanks for replying! It seems not...I think I understand how to restraint it in a rectangle..Could you plz give me more hints?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Transform.rotate**. It has an *origin* property which will help you to rotate the widget with an offset. All you need to do is update the angle on Panupdate accordingly. Below is a code that I used to create this

```
                          Transform.rotate(
                            origin: Offset(125, 0),
                            angle: torad(angle), //function to convert degree to radians
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onPanUpdate: (dragUpdateDetails) {
                                BlocProvider.of<ABloc>(context)
                                    .add(Dragged()); //bloc event to update the position of draggable object as per your convenience
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                  height: 30,
                                  width: 30,
                                  child: CircularWidget(),
                                  color: Colors.transparent),
                            ),
                          ),
```

Comment: Please provide a working example, either by editing JINGYA HAN code or posting a small understandable example.

Comment: @Lulupointu you can check the code that I used for creating the same effect. Pan function still needs some work. But I believe this way we can achieve the desired output