# Flutter: How to set boundaries for a Draggable widget?

Tags: flutter, draggable

I'm trying to create a drag and drop game. I would like to make sure that the `Draggable` widgets don't get out of the screen when they are dragged around.

I couldn't find an answer to this specific question. Someone asked something similar about constraining draggable area [Constraining Draggable area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216747/constraining-draggable-area) but the answer doesn't actually make use of `Draggable`.

To start with I tried to implement a limit on the left-hand side.

I tried to use a Listener with `onPointerMove`. I've associated this event with a limitBoundaries method to detect when the `Draggable` exits from the left side of the screen. This part is working as it does print in the console the `Offset` value when the `Draggable` is going out `(position.dx < 0)`. I also associated a setState to this method to set the position of the draggable to `Offset(0.0, position.dy)` but this doesn't work.

Could anybody help me with this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Draggable Test',
      home: GamePlay(),
    );
  }
}

class GamePlay extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 360,
                height: 400,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.lightGreen,
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    width: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 190,
                height: 400,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.purple,
                    width: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          DragObject(
              key: GlobalKey(),
              initPos: Offset(365, 0.0),
              id: 'Item 1',
              itmColor: Colors.orange),
          DragObject(
            key: GlobalKey(),
            initPos: Offset(450, 0.0),
            id: 'Item 2',
            itmColor: Colors.pink,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DragObject extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;
  final Offset initPos;
  final Color itmColor;

  DragObject({Key key, this.id, this.initPos, this.itmColor}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DragObjectState createState() => _DragObjectState();
}

class _DragObjectState extends State<DragObject> {
  GlobalKey _key;
  Offset position;
  Offset posOffset = Offset(0.0, 0.0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
    _key = widget.key;
    position = widget.initPos;
    super.initState();
  }

  void _getRenderOffsets() {
    final RenderBox renderBoxWidget = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final offset = renderBoxWidget.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    posOffset = offset - position;
  }

  void _afterLayout(_) {
    _getRenderOffsets();
  }

  void limitBoundaries(PointerEvent details) {
    if (details.position.dx < 0) {
      print(details.position);
      setState(() {
        position = Offset(0.0, position.dy);
      });
    }
  }



@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: position.dx,
      top: position.dy,
      child: Listener(
        onPointerMove: limitBoundaries,
        child: Draggable(
          child: Container(
            width: 80,
            height: 80,
            color: widget.itmColor,
          ),
          feedback: Container(
            width: 82,
            height: 82,
            color: widget.itmColor,
          ),
          childWhenDragging: Container(),
          onDragEnd: (drag) {
            setState(() {
              position = drag.offset - posOffset;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this. I tweaked this from: [Constraining Draggable area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216747/constraining-draggable-area) .

```
  ValueNotifier<List<double>> posValueListener = ValueNotifier([0.0, 0.0]);
  ValueChanged<List<double>> posValueChanged;
  double _horizontalPos = 0.0;
  double _verticalPos = 0.0;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  
    posValueListener.addListener(() {
      if (posValueChanged != null) {
        posValueChanged(posValueListener.value);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
           _buildDraggable(),
        ]));
  }
  
  _buildDraggable() {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100),
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            final handle = GestureDetector(
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  _verticalPos =
                      (_verticalPos + details.delta.dy / (context.size.height))
                          .clamp(.0, 1.0);
                  _horizontalPos =
                      (_horizontalPos + details.delta.dx / (context.size.width))
                          .clamp(.0, 1.0);
                  posValueListener.value = [_horizontalPos, _verticalPos];
                },
                child: Container(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                    width: 110.0,
                    height: 170.0,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.black87,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black54),
                  ),
                ));

            return ValueListenableBuilder<List<double>>(
              valueListenable: posValueListener,
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, List<double> value, Widget child) {
                return Align(
                  alignment: Alignment(value[0] * 2 - 1, value[1] * 2 - 1),
                  child: handle,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround for this issue. It's not exactly the output I was looking for but I thought this could be useful to somebody else.

Instead of trying to control the drag object during dragging, I just let it go outside of my screen and I placed it back to its original position in case it goes outside of the screen.

Just a quick note if someone tries my code, I forgot to mention that I'm trying to develop a game for the web. The output on a mobile device might be a little bit odd!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Draggable Test',
      home: GamePlay(),
    );
  }
}

class GamePlay extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 360,
                height: 400,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.lightGreen,
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    width: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 190,
                height: 400,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.purple,
                    width: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          DragObject(
              key: GlobalKey(),
              initPos: Offset(365, 0.0),
              id: 'Item 1',
              itmColor: Colors.orange),
          DragObject(
            key: GlobalKey(),
            initPos: Offset(450, 0.0),
            id: 'Item 2',
            itmColor: Colors.pink,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DragObject extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;
  final Offset initPos;
  final Color itmColor;

  DragObject({Key key, this.id, this.initPos, this.itmColor}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DragObjectState createState() => _DragObjectState();
}

class _DragObjectState extends State<DragObject> {
  GlobalKey _key;
  Offset position;
  Offset posOffset = Offset(0.0, 0.0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
    _key = widget.key;
    position = widget.initPos;
    super.initState();
  }

  void _getRenderOffsets() {
    final RenderBox renderBoxWidget = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final offset = renderBoxWidget.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    posOffset = offset - position;
  }

  void _afterLayout(_) {
    _getRenderOffsets();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: position.dx,
      top: position.dy,
      child: Listener(
        child: Draggable(
          child: Container(
            width: 80,
            height: 80,
            color: widget.itmColor,
          ),
          feedback: Container(
            width: 82,
            height: 82,
            color: widget.itmColor,
          ),
          childWhenDragging: Container(),
          onDragEnd: (drag) {
            setState(() {
              if (drag.offset.dx > 0) {
                position = drag.offset - posOffset;
              } else {
                position = widget.initPos;
              }
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm still interested if someone can find a proper solution to the initial issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

you could use the property `onDragEnd:` of the widget **Draggable** and before setting the new position compare it with the height or width of your device using **MediaQuery** and update only if you didn't pass the limits of your screen, else set the new position to the initial one.

Example bellow :

```
Positioned(
                      left: position.dx,
                      top: position.dy,
                      child: Draggable(
                        maxSimultaneousDrags: 1,
                        childWhenDragging:
                            Opacity(opacity: .2, child: rangeEvent(context)),
                        feedback: rangeEvent(context),
                        axis: Axis.vertical,
                        affinity: Axis.vertical,
                        onDragEnd: (details) => updatePosition(details.offset),
                        child: Transform.scale(
                          scale: scale,
                          child: rangeEvent(context),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
```

In the method `updatePosition`, you verify the new position before updating:

```
  void updatePosition(Offset newPosition) => setState(() {
        if (newPosition.dy > 10 &&
            newPosition.dy < MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9) {
          position = newPosition;
        } else {
          position = const Offset(0, 0);// initial possition 
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass Draggable.
You can start here:

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LimitedDraggable<T> extends Draggable {
  const LimitedDraggable({
    super.key,
    required super.child,
    required super.feedback,
    super.data,
    super.axis,
    super.childWhenDragging,
    super.feedbackOffset = Offset.zero,
    super.dragAnchorStrategy = childDragAnchorStrategy,
    super.affinity,
    super.maxSimultaneousDrags,
    super.onDragStarted,
    super.onDragUpdate,
    super.onDraggableCanceled,
    super.onDragEnd,
    super.onDragCompleted,
    super.ignoringFeedbackSemantics = true,
    super.ignoringFeedbackPointer = true,
    super.rootOverlay = false,
    super.hitTestBehavior = HitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
    super.allowedButtonsFilter,
  });

  @override
  MultiDragGestureRecognizer createRecognizer(
      GestureMultiDragStartCallback onStart) {
    newOnStart(Offset offset) {
      //TODO REPLACE WITH VARIABLE
      if (offset.dx > 200) {
        return onStart(offset);
      }
      return null;
    }

    return super.createRecognizer(newOnStart);
  }
}
```