# Constrain stack area for Positioned widget

Tags: flutter, constraints, draggable

I have a Positioned widget that is draggable, by using Offset and wrapping it inside a Gesture Detector to update its position, and I want to constrain the area that this widget can move, so it cannot go beyond the boundaries. The structure is like this:

- Scaffold -> Stack -> Positioned(Circle)

As it is shown below, I want the circle to move only in the are inside the gray lines. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constraining Draggable area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216747/constraining-draggable-area)

Comment: I checked it before, it doesn't answer my question @tomerpacific. To clarify, the Positioned is like this: Positioned(left: position!.dx, top: position!.dy) and inside of it I have this that updates the position when it is moved by user ->   

onPanUpdate: (details) {
                setState(() {
                  position = Offset(
                    position!.dx + details.delta.dx,
                    position!.dy + details.delta.dy,
                  );
                });
              },

Maybe something inside of this should be changed to achieve what I intend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide 2x value as limit, I did for touch position purpose.
also, both dx and dy axis can work separately. If you don't want it, you can combine two condition on a single setState.

**Result**

[image]

**Widget**

```dart
class HomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeWidgetState createState() => _HomeWidgetState();
}

class _HomeWidgetState extends State<HomeWidget> {
  double dx = 0;
  double dy = 0;

  get limit => 50;
  get containerSize => 50;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              left: limit * .5,
              child: Container(
                height: constraints.maxHeight,
                width: 5,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: limit * .5,
              child: Container(
                width: constraints.maxWidth,
                height: 5,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: dy - containerSize * .5,
              left: dx - containerSize * .5,
              child: Container(
                height: containerSize,
                width: containerSize,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.deepPurple,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onPanUpdate: (details) {
                if (details.localPosition.dx > limit)
                  setState(() {
                    dx = details.localPosition.dx;
                  });
                if (details.localPosition.dy < constraints.maxHeight - limit)
                  setState(() {
                    dy = details.localPosition.dy;
                  });

                print(" $dx, $dy ");
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you test my widget? And about drag I gave more flexibility to the user as I mention on answer. Can you add a gif that you like to archive?

Comment: It constraints the movement, but also the circle becomes very difficult to drag and moves kind of weird. Maybe I am not getting it right to implement in my code.

Comment: Yours works great. I will work to adapt mine based on your code. I will mark it as a solution. Thanks!

Comment: hey guys, do you happen to know how it would be with a bigger circle?. I mean, having the containerSize being higher than 50?. Thank you.

Comment: @JhonCharles that should work, try to use `containerSize` and `limit`

Comment: can you please help me with right and top side to limit container it would be great. Please help me

Comment: @VishalParmar you can create a question and the link ,

Comment: @MDYeasinSheikh Yes sure let me ask new question share you link here

Comment: @MDYeasinSheikh here is the new question please help me with this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76735171/constrain-stack-area-for-positioned-widget-from-all-side