# Constrain stack area for Positioned widget from all side

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, position, gesturedetector

I am referring to the below question and I am able to achieve the left and bottom sides of constrain but I want to achieve the top and left sides of constrain so can anyone suggest to me how to achieve the limit for the top and right sides of constrain

Below is the reference link from which I have achieved the left and bottom limits.

And Also my container height will be any because the user can able to resize it on drag. so how can I manage to constrain for any size of the container?

[In this question I got answers for the bottom and left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68989818/constrain-stack-area-for-positioned-widget/68990177?noredirect=1#comment135276943_68990177)

Comment: can you include your sample code-snippet